# Marginalising over standard deviation of normal to get the posterior on mean

Tags: marginal-distribution, pymc

I am trying to understand the concepts of Bayesian data analysis by examples. I have managed to "do" something, and I would like some advise on where I have gone wrong.

My data is that I have 50 students who take a test and score in the range [0, 1.0], I refer to this as $y$. I would like to calculate the posterior distribution of their mean score $P(\mu|y)$ assuming that the scores are normally distributed with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\tau$.

Looking at other examples, I was able to do the following in Pymc:

```
import pymc as pm
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate fake data
data_scores = np.random.normal(0.5, 0.1, size=50)


mu = pm.Uniform("mu", lower=0, upper=1)
tau = pm.Uniform("tau", lower=0, upper=500)
scores = pm.Normal("score", mu=mu, tau=tau, observed=True, value=data_scores)
model = pm.Model([scores, mu, tau])
mcmc = pm.MCMC(model)
mcmc.sample(40000, 10000, 1)

mu_samples = mcmc.trace('mu')[:]

plt.hist(mu_samples, bins=30)
plt.show()
```

Which produces a nice histogram.

However, I am confused because I feel like I have calculated $P(\mu, \tau| y)$ and hence now need to marginalise of $\tau$ before considering the distribution of $\mu$.

Eventually I want to use this compare how to classes did on a test, but I am at a very basic level of understanding right now so any comments are appreciated.

Comment: Observation: the normal model seems somewhat strange compared to your verbal explanation of the test scores. If the test scores are restricted to $[0,1]$, then $y$ (not just the mean parameter $\mu$) should be restricted to that interval.

Comment: Thanks for the observation and you are correct - I certainly am concerned that I could get a tail of the probability outside the range. May I ask what you would suggest?

Comment: Sounds like you'd need to create your own step method in pymc, or perhaps you could use a Beta distribution instead of Normal. I'm not an expert on this, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you do not 'calculate' $p(\mu,\tau \mid y)$. Instead, you samples from it (in the sense that MCMC methods sample from their target distributions).  If you sample from the joint distribution of $(\mu,\tau)$ and ignore the value of $\tau$, you have a sample from the marginal distribution of $\mu$ - this is essentially what the concepts of joint and marginal distributions mean. Therefore, your `mu_samples` can be interpreted as a sample from $p(\mu \mid y)$ and there is no need to do any special 'marginalization' to your samples.

However, analytically marginalizing over some variables, if possible, may improve the performance of an MCMC algorithm.